# Datatables doesnt get fit width columns on print?

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I try to print datatables, but why when I print it doesnt get fit width coulmns,?
here's my result [Screenshot from 2016-10-17 06-38-39.png](https://postimg.org/image/i0eue3xhh/)

any way to add in my code.? I'm totaly newbie

Comment: You can post your code by simply posting it in your question, highlighting it and clicking the `{}` button so it gets formatted properly.

Answer (score 0):

Assign your table columns a width.